# Provide sagemaker processing job with an entrypoint in UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker

I'm currently working with sagemaker processing jobs and I'm gonna need to write some code to create my own jobs in python. But for now, I'm trying to figure out how to do this in UI so here's my question.

I was able to successfully pass to my job a container built from the following dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

    ADD process.py /
    ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/process.py"]
```

Then I setup everything in UI, left entrypoint section empty and it actually worked: I could see the result file appeared in S3.
Now I'm trying to remove this entrypoint statement from Dockerfile and pass it via this section:
[entrypoint section in AWS UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdf5H.png)

So far I've tried these options:

```
1) ["python3", "/process.py"]
2) ["python3", "process.py"]
3) [python3, process.py]
4) [python3, /process.py]
5) python3 /process.py
6) python3 process.py
7) "python3 process.py"
8) "python3 /process.py"
```

All of these failed with: " ClientError: API error (400): failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: ""python3 /process.py"": stat "python3 /process.py": no such file or directory: unknown "

How do I set up the entrypoint properly in UI in AWS console?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I simply needed to specify a path for the desired script, in my case it was:

```
/process.py
```

No python3, no [], no "" are needed.